# How to read a binary file and write it in a txt or csv file using python?

Tags: python-3.x, binaryfiles

I have a binary file (.man), containing data that I want to read, using python 3.7. The idea is to convert this binary file into a txt or a csv file.

I know the total number of values in the binary file but not the number of bytes per value.

I have red many post talking about binary file but none was helpful...

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Provide us some code and say where you got stuck

Comment: If you don't know the number of bytes per value then you will only get a long list of useless numbers.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Indeed, this is exactly what I have...  If I know the number of bytes per value, what can it change ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution I found is that:

```
    import struct
    import numpy as np

    data =[]

    with open('binary_file', "rb") as f:
        while len(data)<length(binary_file):
            data.extend([struct.unpack('f',f.read(4))])
```

Of course, this works because I know that the encoding is simple precision.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, yes.

```
with open('file.man', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
print(data)  # binary values represented as string
```

Opening a file with the optimal parameter 'rb' means that it will read a binary file and translate it to ASCII (abstracted) for you.

Comment: I would like to add that depending on the data, you might need to import struct and unpack the bytes (you need the number of bytes per value). Furthermore, you can simply use numpy which unpacks the data for you: `numpy.fromfile`

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer.
When I run these lines, I have a variable called data but with value "list object of builtins module". Do you think I need to use struct ?

Comment: @UlysseVigny Can you update the question with the output? Essentially, you cant read a a binary file if you don't know the bits per value. How do you know much of a chunk to read for it to make sense? It could be 8bytes, 16, etc.

Comment: i had access to the number of bytes so that solved my problem thanks